# Taking the value of a JSON string and get the value

Tags: java, json, parsing, guava

I got the JSON string like this: `{Numbers: [10,20,30]}` and I want to parse the value for `Numbers`, and save it as a `List`:

```
[10,20,30]
```

Does anything in Guava do this? Can't use any other 3rd party libraries than that or built in's. (On java 7).

Comment: YOY can't you use other libraries??  JSON really should be built into the JDK, but I'm guessing at this point Oracle knows whatever paradigm they picked would be viciously criticized by partisans of the other schemes.  But it is impractical to build any semi-modern Java app without JSON support.

Answer (score 1):

No, but gson does. Declare a class like

```
class C {
    private List<Integer> Numbers;
}
```

call

```
new Gson().fromJson(s, C.class);
```

and you're done.

However, it's not very nice. The list should be called lowercase `numbers` and maybe it should be an array instead. For the former, look at [FieldNamingStrategy](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingStrategy.html) and the letter should AFAIK work simply declaring it like `int[] numbers`.

## Update

Sorry for not reading the question properly. This simple thing can be handled with regexes and Guava in a few lines:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("\\{Numbers:\\[([\\d, ]+)\\]\\}");

List<Integer> parse(String input) {
    input = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.removeFrom(input);
    final Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(input);
    checkArgument(matcher.matches());
    input = matcher.group(1);
    final Iterable<String> split = Splitter.on(',').split(input);
    final List<Integer> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (final String s : split) result.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    return result;
}
```

It works, but you really shouldn't try to avoid libraries in case it gets more complicated. JSON is rather flexible and handling it all manually would require to write a proper parser and handle object creation and whatever, which sort of means reimplementing Gson or another library.